# Oracle update not working

Tags: oracle

Hello everyone i've tried to update  a row in my database  using sqlplus the query is executed but the values still the same
here is my code:

```
update pilote set nom= 'yees' where id_pilote= 111;
```

1 row updated

Comment: It's not 100% clear from your question what the problem is. It would be better if you added the result of running SELECT nom FROM PILOTE WHERE ID_PILOTE = 111; before and after your update.

Comment: And when you edit your question, make sure to indicate whether you're running the `SELECT` statement in the same session or in a different session.  Assuming you're new to Oracle, my guess is that you're changing the data in one session, not committing, and then trying to read the data in another session and not seeing the change.  You need to `commit` after your update for the change to be visible to others.

Comment: i've needed just a commit thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use Commit Command after update and again re query table contents